# ERROR Disk error while locking directory /var/kafka-logs in 3.10 Kafka

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, portainer

I am using Kafka 3.1.0, Portainer 2.9.0 and docker 20.10.11 to build a 1 broker, 1 consumer and 1 producer cluster.
I am trying to map the log dirs via the docker-compose from the container to the host machine in order to persist the content of that directory (because if the container falls that information will be lost). I know it is recommended to have more than 1 broker, but since I am just testing this feature, I don't want to overcomplicate myself.
The problem I get is

```
 ERROR Disk error while locking directory /var/kafka-logs (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel)
 java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /var/kafka-logs/.lock
[2022-03-31 12:00:53,986] ERROR [KafkaServer id=1] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

I have checked and the user that executes the broker has all permissions (since I created that directory with my Dockerfile).

```
RUN mkdir /var/kafka-logs \
  && chown -R kafka:kafka /var/kafka-logs \
  && chmod -R 777 /var/kafka-logs
```

I have seen that this problem was a thing in the 3.0 version and was fixed in the 3.1, and also that it only happened in Windows, so I don't know the source of this problem.

Edit: I have checked and even without the mapping it still prints that error. It must be a problem of changing the log.dirs property to a non /tmp directory, because if I leave the default configuration it works just fine.
By default I mean the following:

```
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
```

My docker-compose:

```
version: "3.8"

networks:
    net:
        external: true

services:

  kafka-broker1:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/repo/kafka:2.13_3.1.0_v0.1
    volumes:
      - /var/volumes/kafka/config/server1.properties:/opt/kafka/config/server.properties
    networks:
      - net

 kafka-producer:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/repo/kafka:2.13_3.1.0_v0.1
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    networks:
      - net
   
  kafka-consumer:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/repo/kafka:2.13_3.1.0_v0.1
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    networks:
      - net
```

Comment: How are you actually starting the container?  If you have some sort of mount over the `/var/kafka-logs` directory then the ownership and permissions of the mounted directory will take precedence over anything you do in the Dockerfile.

Comment: I have edited the question in order to add my docker-compose. I don't mount anything over that directory. I have tried changing the directory to others but I keep getting the same error

Comment: By the way, your "producer and consumer" aren't needed. In other words, you've started three brokers independent of each other when you can just use `docker exec` into one of them to run Kafka CLI scripts... Besides this, how are you actually configuring the volume mount?

Comment: Yeah, I just created them to test if kafka was completely functional instead of creating python or java classes. I don't fully understand your question. Are you refering about the file server.properties? Or about the directory /var/kafka-logs?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I have been creating a few docker images and the container with the same name and it didn't picked the newest image.

Once I erased the rest of images and the container picked the lastest it all worked just fine, so it was basically a problem of not having enough permissions to get the lock of that directory.